# Android: Force Crash with Uncaught Exception in Thread

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm developing an app, and every once in a while one of my background worker threads will have an uncaught exception of one sort or another. These exceptions crash that thread, but since it's not on the UI thread the App keeps running. **How can I force these uncaught exceptions in the background threads to crash the whole app?** It would be nice if the same contextual crash information (such as the stack trace) were available.

I want to do this so that when I release the app to my testers it doesn't become unresponsive. Instead, when the background thread has an uncaught exception the App will go to it's crash handler and send me a report (I'm using ACRA, but that shouldn't matter). That's better than an app that silently fails.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but I was asking myself the same question.

We use Crashlytics in Production, but if the app is build for development, some assertion are enabled, and logging an error actually throws it, so that we developer can detect any incorrect behavior.

But as you remarked, throwing an error in a background thread doesn't crash the app.

To ensure the app crashes immediately when build for development we simply use an Handler on the main looper to throw the exception on the main thread.

It looks a bit like this :

```
public static void assertTrue(boolean condition, String msg) {
    if (condition) {
        return;
    }

    final IllegalStateException e = new IllegalStateException(message);
    if (BuildConfig.RELEASE) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        return;
    }

    Log.e("ASSERT", message, e);
    if (Looper.getMainLooper() != Looper.myLooper()) {
        mMainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                throw e;
            }
        });
    }

    throw e;
}
```

Comment: While this looks like a promising solution a few things are unclear to me:

1. How do you avoid Intellij errors for "uncaught exception" in run()
2. Where do you get the mainThreadHandler in this static context?

Answer (score 2):

**Original version below**

Actually, after further testing I have found that you can simplify your code by just handing the exception to your main thread directly.

```
public static <T extends Exception> void throwOnMainThread(T exception) {
    Thread mainThread = Looper.getMainLooper().getThread();
    mainThread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(mainThread, exception);
}
```

This will crash the main thread from anywhere and is safe to call even without setting a custom UncaughtExceptionHandler.

**Original answer:**

Consider the following static method for crashing the main thread from a background thread:

```
public static <T extends Exception> void throwOnMainThread(final T exception) {
    Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
            currentThread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(currentThread, exception);
        }
    });
}
```

First we get a Handler for the Main Thread via the main Looper. Then we post a Runnable which will invoke the UncaughtExceptionHandler of that thread and hand it our exception.

Put this into a utils class and you will be able to throw exceptions on the main thread from basically anywhere.

Crashing the main thread could then be achieved by using

```
ThreadUtils.throwOnMainThread(new RuntimeException());
```

for example.

Comment: the new answer does not cause the app to crash for me, but the post-method does work

Answer (score 1):

you can catch your uncaught exception in class that implement `java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

- create a class that implements the UncaughtExceptionHandler and put the behavior you want in `uncaughtException` overidden function. 
  you can do in this function any behavior you want like send logs to server, show custom crash dialog to user etc.
- in your activity/thread add `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`; and give an instance of your exception handler class.

Comment: This does not work for all Executor implementations. Some of them don't call the handler. You have to override `afterExecute` and rethrow the RuntimeException or Error from there to force it to crash.